# JavaFx 8 ScrollPane removeListener

Tags: javafx-8

Using JavaFx 8 I need to be able to remove a Listener and reinstate it in order to prevent code being triggered when it should not be. The following is the code that adds the Listener. I have tried a number of different ways to remove the Listener, but none appeared to be successful. The following code relates to the Listener that I want to remove (or disable / enable) :

```
    import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;

    private ScrollPane c_fX_ScrollPane;

     c_fX_ScrollPane.vvalueProperty().addListener(
            (ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable,
                    Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {

                fn_HandleScrollPaneVerticalValue(oldValue.doubleValue(),
                        newValue.doubleValue());
            });
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove it, don't you need a reference to it? Therefore, you would need to instantiate the ChangeListener outside of the `addListener()` method invocation, and use that same reference on the  `removeListener()` invocation.

```
ChangeListener listener = new ChangeListener(){
    @Override public void changed(ObservableValue o,Object oldVal, 
             Object newVal){
                fn_HandleScrollPaneVerticalValue(oldValue.doubleValue(),
                        newValue.doubleValue());
            });

c_fX_ScrollPane.vvalueProperty().addListener(listener);
c_fX_ScrollPane.vvalueProperty().removeListener(listener);
```

Comment: I could not get that or other similar alternatives to work. What I ended up doing was creating a Class to use as the Listener. In that Class there is a Boolean flag that can be turned off or on to enable or disable it. That appears to work satisfactorily.